# Ajax CSS bugg. How do i prevent from double click in order for the css to apply?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

i have a div that says "on",

And i created a ajax function that everytime a user click the div. It will change the "on" to "off" (A query based on the users column will echo out if the div id is on or off ) and if the user clicks again it will switch it back to "on" again. This is how my code looks like

```
$(".buttons2").click(function(){

    var d = $(this).attr("id");

    if(d == "off")
    {
        $(".buttons2").css("background-position" , "0 -30px");
        $(".buttons2").attr("id", "on");
    }
    else if(d == "on")
    {
        $(".buttons2").css("background-position" , "0 -1px");
        $(".buttons2").attr("id", "off");
    }
});
});
```

My problem is that, in order for the function to work, i have to click the div 2 times. What's the problem?

Comment: Don't use `id` attribute to store a *variable*, use [`data-`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) attributes.

Comment: you can use plain js fot he id: `this.id`. Will be faster (and IMO easier to read)

Comment: you probably didn't initially set the background position, causing it to not be set until after a click.

Comment: What is the initial value of the id?

Comment: Kevin, the first click will set it to to the -30 or -1, dispite it's initial value (being none).

Comment: do you have to doubleclick it each time, or only the first?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not use the ID tag like that! Changing an ID shouldn't really happen (unless you have a very good reason). A reason your code might not work is because the first value of the ID might not be right, or because the ID is not made to be change. The code provided in the question should just work.

One way would be by classes and toggle those. Easier to understand like this (IMO):

```
.buttons2{
    background-position: 0 -30px;
}
.toggled{
    background-position: 0  -1px;
}

<div class="buttons2"> Some Content</div>
```

And then use jquery to toggle it:

```
$('.buttons2').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('toggled');
});
```

I changed the `$('.buttons2')` in your code to `$(this)`. I'm assuming there is only one `.button` (which, kinda ironicly, would make `id="button2`), so we use the 'this' to select it (much like your `var d`).

It's suggested in the comment you use `data-*` values for the intent you want. While the `data-*` attributes are intented for this (eg: `data-state="on"`), I choose classes because of jQuery's [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) because I find this easier for toggling.

Comment: It might have something to do with the values it has on init. Can't really say. Might the DOM doesn't like changing ID's. This does work :) (and IMO easier to understand, and afaik faster then JSing it)

Comment: So, you posted an answer that is just a different way of doing it, but actually don't really know what was wrong with the code the OP already had?  The best answers explain what was wrong with the original code and then show a good way to solve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

But it's a switch button. It depends on what the user has in the column. If the user has for example online= 1, it should start to switch in the opposite way. Off>on , on>Off. The div is based on a query

Comment: I could be wrong but the first line, "`i have a div that says "on" `" suggests it always stats with on, not depending on the user/query :)

Comment: This should not be an answer.  This should be a comment to your original question.

Comment: Sorry i'll change that.